# Android Proguard SqlCipher NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, sqlcipher

Have been battling with Proguard all day and have tried many examples and solutions on the official Proguard site as well as StackOverflow.

I have a large project I need to obfuscate, which has a number of referenced library projects and Jars.

I am getting 725 warnings from proguard from 2 libs,  com.google.common and twitter4j.

I can happily get the project to compile if I add the following:

```
-dontwarn com.google.common.**

-dontwarn twitter4j.**
```

However, the app crashes instantly on open, so this seems to just be a way of hiding an issue, not fixing it.

The proguard-project.txt is in the project root and its config is in the project.properties file as below.

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Here is my proguard-project.txt file

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dontshrink

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.code.**  { *; }
-keep class java.lang.management.**  { *; }
-keep class com.google.common.** { *; }

-libraryjars C:/adt-bundle-windows/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar
-libraryjars C:/adt-bundle-windows/sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars C:/svn/android/MyAppLib/trunk/libs/commons-codec.jar
-libraryjars C:/svn/android/MyAppLib/trunk/libs/sqlcipher.jar
-libraryjars C:/svn/android/MyAppLib/trunk/libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar
-libraryjars C:/svn/android/MyAppLib/trunk/libs/guava-r09.jar
-libraryjars C:/adt-bundle-windows/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar
-libraryjars C:/adt-bundle-windows/sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars C:/adt-bundle-windows/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19/libs/maps.jar
-libraryjars C:/adt-bundle-windows/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19/libs/effects.jar
-libraryjars C:/adt-bundle-windows/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19/libs/usb.jar

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-dontwarn android.support.**
```

And Here is the truncated error log

```
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Note: there were 9032 duplicate class definitions.
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find superclass or interface javax.management.DynamicMBean
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$2: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$2: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$2: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.common.base.Function: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.common.base.Function: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.common.base.Functions: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.common.base.Functions: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.common.base.Functions$ConstantFunction: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable

*********************************** ANOTHER 500 LINES OF com.google.common ERRORS ******************************************

[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.CommonsLoggingLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.CommonsLoggingLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType

*********************************** ANOTHER 500 LINES OF twitter4j ERRORS ******************************************

[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] Warning: there were 725 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-01-13 14:00:07 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

EDIT** Stack trace from crash, clearer now that it is linked to sqlcipher

```
E/Database(18203): Can't find SQLiteDatabase.mNativeHandle
E/Cursor(18203): Can't find net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteCompiledSql
E/Cursor(18203): Can't find net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteQuery
E/Cursor(18203): Can't find net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteProgram
E/Cursor(18203): Can't find net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteStatement
E/CursorWindow(18203): Can't find net/sqlcipher/CursorWindow
 D/AndroidRuntime(18203): Shutting down VM
 W/dalvikvm(18203): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415e9ba8)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18203): Process: com.mycompany.android.myapp, PID: 18203
E/AndroidRuntime(18203): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sqlcipher/CursorWindow
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(Runtime.java:421)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:362)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at com.mycompany.android.myapplib.sqlite.MyProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4790)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18203): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteStatement
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    ... 22 more
E/AndroidRuntime(18203): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteProgram
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    ... 22 more
E/AndroidRuntime(18203): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteQuery
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    ... 22 more
E/AndroidRuntime(18203): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteCompiledSql
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    ... 22 more
E/AndroidRuntime(18203): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no field with name='mNativeHandle' signature='I' in class Lnet/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteDatabase;
E/AndroidRuntime(18203):    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the crash when application start ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the config I've used in the past for SQLcipher

```
-keep public class net.sqlcipher.** {
    *;
}

-keep public class net.sqlcipher.database.** {
    *;
}
```

Comment: isn't the second statement implicitly included in the first statement, as it just makes another keep on a subpackage which is normally handled with the **  ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to add thoses 2 lines in your proguard file :

```
-dontwarn javax.management.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep class net.sqlcipher.** { *; }
-dontwarn net.sqlcipher.**
```

For more [information](https://dbflow.gitbook.io/dbflow/usage2/advanced-usage/sqlciphersupport)